# Error when starting QGIS

Tags: qgis, dll

I have a problem when I start QGIS.

I installed version 3.10 and when I tried to launch it I got the first error window (the one on the left).
I tried to install previous versions (3.8, 3.4) but nothing has changed.

Currently, if I try to launch the program (version 3.8) the window on the right appears first and then the window on the left.

[image]

What can I do?

Comment: On the QGIS website https://www.qgis.org/fr/site/forusers/download.html, try to reinstall with independent installer or OSGeo4W installer.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Please always provide errors as formatted text rather than pictures.